# Javascript; Does it help the GC to clean up headless variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, garbage-collection

I like having strings with no var name in my javascript simply to `'STATE A TITLE';` since comments `/*can be dull*/` at times.

**Why?**

> If I have a large function that has stages, I feel that it helps me to
> read a nice string title of what happens next to remind me when I
> might be unfocused!

**Question**

Will the one-liner `delete 'THE STRING';` help the GC? or can I leave it headless? *(without var name declaration)*

Comment: `If I have a large function that has stages` !!

Comment: An unreferenced object will not be stored anywhere so, yes, it would be GC'd whenever that client does clean up. But I have to say that just because you "feel" better using strings than comments doesn't make your approach right. I'd suggest you use comments so others will know what you are doing. Also, you know that single line comments can be written as just `//` and not `/**/`, right?

Comment: //lol yes I do.